# Get product select value in module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, select

We needed to have out of stock products show for configurable products. I have managed to get this working all ok, however I have a custom attribute called fulfilment which is a select option for the products so you can set an out of stock message such `Available in 7 days` etc.

I need to get the attribute text in `app/code/local/ModuleCompany/ModuleName/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type.php` but don't seem to be able to however I try.

Inside of `getJsonConfig()` method I try

```
    $custom_stock_attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($currentProduct->getId())->getAttributeText('fulfilment');
```

But just can't seem to get it working. So the question is how do you get attribute value of a select field from a module?

Magento Version: 1.9.2.4

Comment: Have you tried `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($currentProduct->getId())->getFulfilment();`

Comment: Yeah, have tried that too. Doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I have to attach a getFrontend()->getValue() on the call for dropdowns to show up for me

See if this works:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $currentProduct->getId() )
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('fulfilment')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Also, make sure you didn't mean `fulfillment`, instead of `fulfilment`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply! When I try that I just get 'No' as the output value.